# Load and play a gif with javascript onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my website I have three images `1.png, 2.png and 3.png`. When I click on `1.png`, I want the animated gif `1a.gif` to be loaded and shown/updated in the img tag located in `<div id="container">`. When I click on `2.png`, `2a.gif` should be displayed (while `1a.gif` vanishes) and so on... This is my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
 <img src="1.png" onclick="document.getElementById('img').src = '1a.gif'" /> 
 <img src="2.png" onclick="document.getElementById('img').src = '2a.gif'" />
 <img src="3.png" onclick="document.getElementById('img').src = '3a.gif'" />
</div>

<div id="container">
<img id="img" src="1a.gif" />
</div>

</html>
</body>
```

It is working, however unreliable (tested with firefox and chrome)! When I refresh the html page and click on 1.png, than on 2.png ... suddendly at one point only the first frame of the animated gif is shown. I have to click on the same image (1,2 or 3.png) again in order to make the gif run. Why? I am looking for a light weight javascript solution without jquery. I am just asking myself why the gif is not played properly once I click on the image.

As a side note: It would be nice to show a loading image while the gif (5 MB) is loading. I failed to achive that using css:

```
#container {background:url('loading.png') no-repeat; }
```

In this case the loading image doesn't show up at all. Probably because I am updating directly from one (e.g. 1a.gif) to another (e.g. 2a.gif).

Showing it right before loading the gif did not help as well:

```
<img src="1.png" onclick="document.getElementById('img').src = 'loading.png';
document.getElementById('img').src = '1a.gif'" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of implementing this kind of thing, but to keep in line with how you're doing it, you'll want to hook into the `onload` event of the `img`.

Note that in this snippet, I don't have access to your GIFs, so I'm using the dummyimage.com service, which is pretty fast, so you don't see the "loading" for very long.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var img = document.getElementById('img');
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var showImage = function showImage() {
    img.style.display = "inline";
    container.style.backgroundImage = "";
  };
  img.addEventListener('load', showImage);
  img.addEventListener('error', showImage);
  var thumbs = document.getElementsByClassName('thumb');
  for (var i = 0, z = thumbs.length; i < z; i++) {
    var thumb = thumbs[i];
    var handler = (function(t) {
      return function clickThumb() {
        container.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://dummyimage.com/500x500/000/fff.gif&text=loading')";
        img.style.display = "none";
        img.src = t.dataset['image'];
      };
    })(thumb);
    thumb.addEventListener('click', handler);
  }
};
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="1.png" class="thumb" data-image="https://dummyimage.com/500x200/000/fff.gif" />
  <img src="2.png" class="thumb" data-image="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff.gif" />
  <img src="3.png" class="thumb" data-image="https://dummyimage.com/500x500/000/fff.gif" />
</div>

<div id="container">
  <img id="img" class="main" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens bacause the second img is not loaded yet!
I suggest you to put the 2 img in 2 different divs and the use javascript to hide/show the entire div!

Comment: the gif's are so big. I wanted to load them only when x.png is clicked to minimize loading times and traffic.